# Bash Function to Export .bashrc to a Remote Server

Tags: ssh, bash, shell-scripting, bashrc

I am trying to write a bash function shown below. I am trying to scp my `.bashrc` to the target machine. I want to do modify the following function in the below two ways.

1. I want to enter the password only once. Can I cache the password entered for scp and use the same for ssh.
2. I also want to execute `bash --rcfile` from the server rather then from my machine.

My starting example code is below:

```
export_bashrc() {
    scp ~/.bashrc $1:/root/ws_karthik
    ssh $1
    bash --rcfile /root/ws_karthik/.bashrc  
}
```

Can anyone suggest how to get around this issue?

Answer (score 1):

1. Take a look at [sshpass](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sshpass/). If you haven't installed a configuration management tools such as: Puppet, Chef, ... I think you should setup public key authentication and use [pssh](http://www.theether.org/pssh/) to do a same command parallel on many servers at a time. (`pscp` to copy your ~/.bashrc)
2. `$ ssh -t $1 'bash --rcfile /root/ws_karthik/.bashrc'`

Why didn't you copy ~/.bashrc to the home folder of ssh user?